# Using dropzonejs-rails and options

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, dropzone.js

I'm planing use dropzone.js to upload files to my rails app. But I'm having problems to use custom options. I'm using the code from the examples from Dropzone.js.

This is my code:

```
<%= form_for(@document, html: {multipart: true, class: 'dropzone', id: 'myAwesomeDropzone'}) do |f| %>
    <div class="fallback">
      <%= f.file_field :document %><br>
      <%= f.submit 'Upload my document' %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Js code:

```
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function () {
    // disable auto discover
    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

    // "myAwesomeDropzone" is the camelized version of the HTML element's ID
    Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
        paramName: "file", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
        maxFilesize: 2, // MB
        dictDefaultMessage : 'Testing'
    };

});
```

When I try it in the browser, the dropzone works, but ignores the javascript code with the options. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you're configuring your form (and stopping auto-discovery) after the auto discovery has happened, I think. Using your exact same `form_for` tag, I was able to get it working by moving the

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
```

outside of the `turbolinks:load` event and then initializing the new drop zone after the configuration block. My javascript ended up looking like:

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function () {
    // "myAwesomeDropzone" is the camelized version of the HTML element's ID
    Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
        paramName: "file", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
        maxFilesize: 2, // MB
        dictDefaultMessage : 'Testing'
    };

    new Dropzone("#myAwesomeDropzone");
});
```

and this can be further reduced to just

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function () {
  new Dropzone("#myAwesomeDropzone", {
    paramName: "file",
    maxFilesize: 2,
    dictDefaultMessage: 'Testing'
  });
});
```

Comment: Nice! Thanks for the help!

Comment: for what is this line `new Dropzone("#myAwesomeDropzone");`? I was using shrine and jquery-fileupload-rails, but with that line is not uploading my files to S3.

Comment: @exsnake When I was testing, since I had disabled the `autoDiscover` the javascript wasn't doing anything to `#myAwesomeDropzone`, according to the documentation for that plugin, that line is what causes it to add the drop zone onto the form see, "[Creating Dropzones Programatically](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#create-dropzones-programmatically)" in the documentation. Also edited my answer, when I went back to grab that link, I saw you can just pass the options in while initializing.

Comment: @exsnake also take note, not sure if this is causing any problems, but in your fallback form you have a field named `document[document]` and in that drop zone config it looks like it'll try submitting as `file`

Comment: Yeah, I tried changing that `file` to `document[document]`, but didn't work. Maybe I should create a new question.

Comment: @exsnake yeah, not really sure beyond that...never even heard of this library before I saw your question 4 hours ago; and multiple javascript files that may or may not be doing things to each other isn't my strong suit.

Comment: Thanks you for the help!